# What is 1column.phtml in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

what is the equivalent of `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/1column.phtml` in magento 2?
I want to insert custom div inside it.

Comment: app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/page_layout/1column.xml

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you have your environment set up it could be in two places. The fist would be where Douglas stated and the second being: /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/page_layout/1column.xml.

Comment: So in Magento 2 there is no `1-column.phtml`? Is it created dynamically when published to static?